# Удалить пользователя

Tags: php, mysql

Выводится таблица с пользователями, есть кнопка и поле. Как удалить пользователя по username, который вводишь с клавиатуры в поле логин?

```
<?php 
    include 'core/init.php';
    $ath = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users`");
    if($ath)
    {
      // Определяем таблицу и заголовок
      echo "<table border=1>";
      echo "<tr><td>логин</td><td>пароль</td><td>имя</td><td>first_name</td><td>email</td></tr>";
      // Так как запрос возвращает несколько строк, применяем цикл
      while($author = mysql_fetch_array($ath))
      {
        echo "<tr><td>".$author['username']."&nbsp;</td><td>".$author['password']."
        &nbsp </td><td>".$author['first_name']."&nbsp;</td><td>". 
        $author['last_name']."&nbsp;</td><td>".$author['email']."
        &nbsp </td></tr>";
      }
      echo "</table>";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "<p><b>Error: ".mysql_error()."</b><p>";
      exit();
    }
    ?>
    логин:<br>
     <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="submit" value="удалить">
```

Comment: не храните пароль в открытом виде

Answer (score 2):

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);

mysql_query("DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' ");
```

Comment: Только это:
 логин:<br>
     <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="submit" value="удалить">
надо делать в форме, типа

<form action="/script.php" method="POST">
 логин:<br>
     <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="submit" value="удалить">
</form>

Answer (score 0):

С помощью комманды `MySQL`

```
DELETE $username FROM users
```

Comment: а если поточнее?

Comment: Напмсал точнее...

Comment: оно мне удалило все юзеров как только я страницу обновил, а мне нужно что бы в поле вводить юзера и нажать удалить!

Comment: $username =$_POST['username'];
а кнопка удалить должна быть input type="submit"